# Can lein run specific custom code after compiling everything else?

Tags: javafx, clojure

I've been trying to work around the issue [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365409/clojure-cant-import-javafx-classes-with-static-initializers) of building a Clojure JavaFX project that is both compilable and interactive, while still being able to `import` and `proxy` classes that run static initialization.  I trying applying [this patch](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1714) to 1.9.0-master-SNAPSHOT, but no luck.

So my workaround is to initialize the toolkit first, during the compilation step, by making it the first thing in the first dependency.  However, as mentioned   [elsewhere](https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/370zmg/using_clojure_with_javafx_and_making_an_uberjar/), this prevents the compile step from terminating, so I have to kill the toolkit for it to work.

Currently I'm doing this with a thread that runs a 5 second timer, assuming 5s is enough time to compile other files in the same `lein...` invocation, but it's obviously not a good solution.

**Question**:

**Is there a way to run arbitrary Clojure code as the last thing in a `lein compile`, `lein uberjar`, etc?**

For example, ensuring that some .clj file is the very last one to get compiled, or putting something in the project.clj file?  All it needs to do is run `(javafx.application.Platform/exit)` after everything is done compiling.  Searches for lein compilation order usually point to the ordering/sequencing of Clojure vs Java sources.

Comment: I wonder if you could create a custom command as part of a plugin and run e.g. `lein do compile, mycommand`.

Comment: You don’t need a plugin for that. You can create an alias to do that in the project.clj

Comment: It occurred to me a plugin may be necessary, but that seems like overkill.  So how do I use an alias to run `(mycommand arg1 arg2...)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
:aliases {"copy" ["do" "clean" ["jar"] ["scp"]]
          "myalias" ["run" "-m" "com.example.mycommand" "arg1" "arg2"]}
```

in your project.clj, as you want to do.